# Losing map value in variable

Tags: python

Can't understand why I can't assign map result to a variable. It's losing its value.

```
>>> L = 'something'
>>> R = map(lambda x: x * 2, L)
>>> print(list(R))
['ss', 'oo', 'mm', 'ee', 'tt', 'hh', 'ii', 'nn', 'gg']
>>> V = list(R)
>>> print(V)
[]
```

Comment: `map` creates an iterator, not a list; you can only consume it once.

Comment: Calling `V = list(R)` the first time, then `print(V)`, would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 `map` returns an iterator that, once consumed, will yield nothing.
In your case you are consuming it in the first `print(list(R))` call, so in the second one it yields nothing which is the same as `list()` alone.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the map object can be iterated over *only once*. When you print it, that's it. The next time you assign it, it's empty

Instead, try

```
R = map(..)
V = list(R)
print(V)
```